# Polymer SPA without webserver

Tags: html, polymer

I like to build a small .html file with polymer elements in it for documentation purposes. My plan is to keep it simple and simply put it on an SMB share.

How can I make a simple file/folder of html element using polymer elements without using a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to `import` custom element definition without using a web server, because it violates some of browser security policies.

So all `import`s can and will only be done over a server serving the required files.

File system meaning the local files are able to skip some of browser's security checks and so browsers strictly don't allow anything other than static html through the filesystem.